# React Native onBack takes to First Screen issue

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

My application contain drawer navigator and stack navigator. But issue is that when i tried to goback it takes me to first screen even if i am 2-3 stack deep. It don't show previous screen it always takes me to main screen. Below is my App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    ActivityIndicator,
    AsyncStorage,
    Button,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator, SwitchNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import Screen1 from './Screen/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen/Screen3';
import Screen4 from './Screen/Screen4';
import Screen5 from './Screen/Screen5';
import ScreenList from './Screen/ScreenList';

import Login from './Screen/Login';


class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._bootstrapAsync();
    }

    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');

        // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
        // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
    };

    // Render any loading content that you like here
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
                <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

const AppStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1},
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2},
    Screen3: { screen: Screen3},
    Screen4: { screen: Screen4},
    Screen5: { screen: Screen5},
    ScreenList: { screen: ScreenList},
}, {contentComponent: SideBar});


const AuthStack = StackNavigator({Login: { screen: Login}},{headerMode:'none'});

const MyNavigator = SwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
    }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <MyNavigator />;
    }
}
```

From Screen 1, i click on button and go to screen 2 and screen 3 like:

```
onPress={() => navigate('Screen2', { })}
```

And it works fine, but when i go back using bellow code from screen 3 it takes me to screen 1 not screen 2

```
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: try this .goBack({ numberOfPages: 1})

Comment: it does nothing. Why normal stacking not working?

Comment: debug using alert() to make sure you are calling goBack() only once

Comment: i did that... its calling once

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

```
<Button
   onPress={() => goBack('3')}
   title="Go to 3 screen"
 />
```